# Matplotlib: resize axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is a method to resize the entire Figure

`plt.gcf().set_size_inches`

Is it possible to similarly resize just a subplot of a Figure, i.e. Axis?

My xticks currently overlap and I would like to resize the plot accordingly, to:

`len(ticks) * max(tick_lengths)`

The problem with using `set_size_inches` is:

a) it resizes all subplots when a Figure contains more than a single Axis

b) the margins around the Axis and between them are also resized

Comment: Have now, doesn't solve my issue unfortunately

Comment: Can you add a picture of what the problem looks like and what you want to happen?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand the problem. But if you want to change the lower and upper limits of your x-axis, check this part of the matplotlib docu: https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html.

Comment: The limits doesn't solve this. I want to increase the spacing between xticks so to speak

Answer (score 0):

You can change the spacing of the subplots with (amongst other things):

```
subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None,
                wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

For figures with multiple subplots, you might need to change `wspace` or `hspace`. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20subplots_adjust#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) for details.

Alternatively, you could try calling `plt.tight_layout()` after plotting, usually this solves any spacing/overlapping/... problems.

Comment: This doesnt resize a particular Axis though