# resize existing figure and axis matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar to this (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277623/matplotlib-resize-axis), how can I resize an existing figure and axis? For example, I would like to do the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3))
# (3,3) figure
ax.plot(range(10))
fig.savefig("33.pdf")

# (6,3) figure
fig.figsize=(6,3)
ax.plot(range(10))
fig.savefig("63.pdf")
```

but the command `fig.figsize=(6,3)` doesn't work.

Comment: Please see: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_size_inches

Comment: @JodyKlymak: Thanks, the `set_size_inches` call in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306340/6272122) you linked to is what I was looking for!